# tex4ht table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht

I'm working on an ebook and i'm trying to make a main toc at the beginning like

```
1. chapter 1
    1.1 section 
    1.2 section
2. chapter 2
...
```

and minitocs at every chapter like

```
1.1 section
   1.1.1 subsection
1.2 section
...
```

the "minitocs" work fine with

```
\TocAt{chapter,section,subsection}
```

and the maintoc works almost fine with

```
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter,section}
```

but the sections go 1,2,3,4 instead of 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4. I somewhere found the config.cfg

```
\begin{document}
  \ConfigureToc{section}
      {\tocNesting{1}\HCode{<li>}}{ }{}{ }
   \ConfigureToc{subsection}
      {\tocNesting{2}\HCode{<li>}}{ }{}{ }
   \ConfigureToc{subsubsection}
      {\tocNesting{3}\HCode{<li>}}{ }{}{ }
   \Configure{tableofcontents}
      {} {\tocNesting{0}} {} {} {}

   \newcount\c
   \def\tocNesting#1{%
      \expandafter\ifx \csname level#1\endcsname\relax
          \ifnum #1>0 \HCode{<ul>}\fi
          \expandafter\def \csname level#1\endcsname{\HCode{</ul>}}
      \fi
      \c=#1 \advance\c by 1
      \loop
        \csname level\the\c\endcsname
        \expandafter\let \csname level\the\c\endcsname\relax
        \advance\c by 1
      \ifnum \c<10   \repeat
   }
```

now the numbering is correct, but subsections are also printed (which should be an easy fix i guess?) and in some epub-viewers i get an error message like "wrong tag, expected <\li>". Is there a way to configure the main toc to achieve what i want, without affecting the minitocs?

And another question: is it possible to include list of figures and list of tables in each chapter in tex4ht? (like minilof and minilot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you generate Ebook in the Epub 3 format. It requires table of contents in a specific format, where numbered html list is used. It interfered with the section numbering explicitly added by tex4ht, so I disabled the section numbering and used only numbers added by the reading application. It is possible to revert this behavior with the following configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\TocAt{chapter,section,subsection}
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter,section}
\Configure{NavSection}{%
\booltrue{tocnoempty}
\HCode{<li>}}{\HCode{<ol>\Hnewline}}{}{\Tg</ol>\Tg</li>}
\Css{nav\#toc ol{list-style: none;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `NavSection` configuration takes care of the HTML list, in the original version it also suppressed the section numbering. The `\Css` command disables the HTML numbering for TOC.

This is the result:

[image]

Regarding your last question, it should be possible, but it would be better if you could to post a new question with a full MWE.